# How to use the JQuery DataTables "input" plugin with DataTables 1.10

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

The jQuery DataTables ["input" plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/input) was created to allow manual user input of a page number on a paginated display in addition to the typical first, previous, next, last buttons.  The default display shows next and last, with a few page number buttons adjacent to the current page number, so if you're on page 10, perhaps there would be buttons labeled "11", "12", and "13" buttons.  But what if you want to go to page 1000 of 2000?  No easy way to get there.  That is the motivation of the input plugin.

However, this code was written for the "legacy" version of DataTables, the version prior to 1.10.  My application is written for the newer version.

The example quoted on the page uses the pre-1.10 syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
          "sPaginationType": "input"
      } );
  } );
```

I tried making trivial modifications, along the lines of the new syntax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
          "paginationType": "input"
      } );
  } );
```

but it doesn't work.  To be sure, the inputting of the page number works, but all the other buttons are broken, rendering as text:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a simple way to get this plugin to work with the newer DataTables, or is there a better way to get this functionality in that environment?

Comment: Could you share a fiddle ?

Comment: works fine here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/fbyjcuLu/**

Comment: Well, thanks, that's very simple and clean.  Not sure what in my code is breaking it.  It's a place to start from anyway.  Mine is using ajax, etc. but that should not affect this.

Comment: @SteveCohen, no, AJAX etc should not. I tried with several 1.10.x versions, jQuery from 1.8.x to 2.x edge - seems to work all the way. So you must have something else breaking the plugin.

Comment: @davidkonrad - I've cleaned a lot of crud off my page and still the problem remains.  I'm almost certain that the problem has something to do with Bootstrap. Is there some way to add Bootstrap to your fiddle?  I would be interested in seeing the results.  But Bootstrap isn't one of the fiddle options that you can add on the page.  Sorry, I'm neither a JS nor a Fiddle expert.

Comment: @SteveCohen - here with bootstrap 3.3.5 **http://jsfiddle.net/fbyjcuLu/1/**

Comment: @davidkonrad - thanks so much for your fiddles.  They got me to see that my original diagnosis was completely off the mark, and this really was a stupid question - the answer turns out to have been that my page somehow managed without the datatables stylesheet with no difficulties - until now! I had the datatables.bootstrap css but not the datatables one.  D'Oh!

Answer (score 0):

In my case http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css was missing. After adding it everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get nice buttons instead text. I changed source code on next way.
I use FontAwsome icons for this

```
.
var firstClassName = 'fa fa-fast-backward';
var previousClassName = 'fa fa-step-backward mx-2';
var nextClassName = 'fa fa-step-forward mx-2';
var lastClassName = 'fa fa-fast-forward';
.
.
// nFirst.innerHTML = language.sFirst;
// nPrevious.innerHTML = language.sPrevious;
// nNext.innerHTML = language.sNext;
// nLast.innerHTML = language.sLast;
.
nInput.type = 'text';
nInput.pattern = "[1-9]"; //added this line so input field accept only numbers
```