# Goto page number option below in the data-table? Next, Previous and need Goto

Tags: javascript

Pagination should have goto option by default. Not sure whether it is difficult or purposely been not shown in examples. Could someone assist how to add goto page number in datatable?

example is given in https://datatables.net/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
1. Include input.js file
2. $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#example').dataTable({
          "pagingType": "input"
       });
   });
3. Two flavours..For text box #2 and for list box kind of page..include below..you can choose option above and below
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable({
           "pagingType": "listbox"
      });
    });
```

### References

> https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/input
>
> [How to use the JQuery DataTables "input" plugin with DataTables 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505087/how-to-use-the-jquery-datatables-input-plugin-with-datatables-1-10)
>
> [How to change the Page # in DataTables in the Pagination bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789753/how-to-change-the-page-in-datatables-in-the-pagination-bar)
>
> [Desired page in pagination with DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666969/desired-page-in-pagination-with-datatables/30668366#30668366)
>
> http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/select
>
> https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/input